# Angular Flex Layout column with left and right spacing and fixed footer

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

What is the proper way to add a gap on the left and right of the main container on a single column angular flex layout with a static header and fixed footer?

I am seeing from the documentation that fxLayoutGap for columns adds margin to the bottom and when I just use regular css for margin-left/right I get an offset where the main content area is hanging off the right side of the page.

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutGap-API

[starting point](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-msmyts?file=app%2Ftest.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this with css - fxLayoutGap is for spacing child elements of a flex container

Here's an option:

```
<div class="my-container" style="padding: 0 1rem">...</div>
```

Or here's my go-to since it scales down to mobile nicely and constrains too wide of line lengths on large screens:

```
.container {
  // your styles to make it full height, full width, and/or scrollable
}
.page {
  padding: 2rem 1rem 4rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 60rem;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="page">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, hits on almost everything but the fixed footer